# AttributeError when listing all entities from Google App Engine datastore

Tags: python, google-app-engine, app-engine-ndb

Am trying to get all the entities in my datastore,and then display them using HTML. Am trying to do this from inside a `RequestHandler` but i get the error message

`"AttributeError: type object 'Student' has no attribute 'all'"`

This is my `Student` class

```
class Student(ndb.Model):
   banner_id = ndb.IntegerProperty(required=True)
   name=ndb.StringProperty()
   score=ndb.IntegerProperty()
```

And this is the `RequestHandler` code:

```
class MainHandler(webapp2.RequestHandler):
def get(self):
    # Create a HTML table
    table = "<html><head><title>Students Server</title></head><body><table><th>name</th><td>score</th>"
    # Now get a list of all students
    sqry = Student.all()
    sqry.order('name')

        # Use the data collected so far to create a table row and add 
        # it to the table
    table += Student.toTableRow(score)
    # Complete the table
    table += "</table>"
    self.response.write(table)
    self.response.write(studentRegistrationPage)
```

Am trying to retrieve all the students and order the list based on name. Got this idea from [here](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/datastore/queries) where an example like this was given.

```
# Order alphabetically by last name:
q = Person.all()
q.order('last_name')

# Order by height, tallest to shortest:
q = Person.all()
q.order('-height')
```

What am i doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are trying to perform a `db` query but you are using `ndb`.

Have a read of the docs  https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/ndb/queries . Also look at the db/ndb cheat sheet  https://docs.google.com/document/d/1AefylbadN456_Z7BZOpZEXDq8cR8LYu7QgI7bt5V0Iw/mobilebasic?pli=1

With `ndb` the query would be `Person.query()`

Comment: Tim to the rescue,AGAIN. :D